# How to calculate coverage probability in R for the cauchy distribution?

Tags: probability

I know that the coverage probability is $P(|\hat{\theta}-\theta|\leq\epsilon)$. My task is to compare estimators of the Cauchy distribution for the location $\theta$. I've plotted the estimators and calculated their MSE. The estimators include the sample, median, and MLE. I am just stuck on how I would use R to evaluate the coverage probability for these estimators, say for $\epsilon=0.1$.

Thanks

Comment: This and your other questions might be better suited to https://stats.stackexchange.com/. There is a specific tag for `R` there.

Comment: thanks a lot @StubbornAtom